# How to calculate the residue of $f(s)=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^{s-1/2}}{s-1/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

Let $x\in\mathbb{R},\,x>1$, and

$$f(s)= \frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^{s-1/2}}{s-\frac 12}$$

where $s=\sigma+it\in\mathbb{C}$. How do you calculate the residues of $f(s)$ in the critical strip (where $0<\sigma<1)$, assuming the Riemann hypothesis and that all poles are simple to begin with. So for example, how do you calculate the residue of $f(s)$ at $s=\rho=\frac 12+i\gamma$, where $\zeta(s)=0$? What happens without one or both assumptions?

If I use Mathematica for this, I get the expressions ahead, but please note that I would like to know is how Mathematica arrives at these expressions, and under what assumptions.

So, if $s=\frac 12$ Mathematica produces

$$\frac{\log x}{2\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{\zeta’\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\zeta\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{\gamma}{\zeta\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

And if $s=\rho=\frac 12+i\gamma$ and $\zeta(s)=0$ one gets

$$\frac{\zeta(2\rho)x^{i\gamma}}{i\gamma\zeta’(\rho)}$$

So again, my question is, how does Mathematica get to this result?

Comment: What is $x$?  Do you assume the critical zeros are all simple zeros? What happens when you use the usual computation of residues for a simple pole?

Comment: The residues are in terms of (constant terms of) Laurent expansions of zeta on the half line and special values of zeta on $\mathrm{Re}(s) = 1$. RH has little to say here except for the location of the poles. Nonsimple poles present annoying bookkeeping, as there are multiple ways to combine terms from the Laurent expansions to get residues.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Right, so how would you go about it, in this particular case?

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic idea for a simple zero $\rho = \frac{1}{2} + i\gamma$. It is straightforward to modify for multiple zeros.

Write the Laurent expansions of each term around $\rho$, noting that for $\gamma \neq 0$ the only term with a zero is $\zeta(s)$:

\begin{align}
\zeta(s) &= 0 + \zeta'(\rho)(s - \rho) + O\big( (s - \rho)^2 \big) \\
\zeta(2s) &= \zeta(2\rho) + 2\zeta'(2\rho)(s - \rho) + O\big( (s - \rho)^2 \big) \\
X^{s - \frac{1}{2}} &= X^{\rho - \frac{1}{2}} + (\log X) X^{\rho - \frac{1}{2}} (s - \rho) + O\big( (s - \rho)^2 \big) \\
s - \tfrac{1}{2} &= (\rho - \tfrac{1}{2}) + (s - \rho).
\end{align}

The residue at $s = \rho$ will come from the coefficient of $(s - \rho)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of

$$\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)} \frac{X^{s - \frac{1}{2}}}{s - \frac{1}{2}},$$

which direct insertion reveals comes from the constant terms in the Laurent expansions of $\zeta(2s), X^{s - \frac{1}{2}}$, and $(s - \tfrac{1}{2})$, and the coefficient of $\zeta(s)$. This shows that the residue is

$$ \frac{\zeta(2\rho)}{\zeta'(\rho)} \frac{X^{\rho - \frac{1}{2}}}{\rho - \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\zeta(2\rho)}{\zeta'(\rho)} \frac{X^{i \gamma}}{i \gamma}. $$

For simple zeros, note that this is equivalent to taking the values at $s = \rho$ of the various nonzero, nonpolar terms, and multiplying by the residue of $\zeta(s)^{-1}$.

Comment: This is the residue when the zero is simple. Otherwise $\zeta'(\rho) = 0$, and things are much more annoying to write down (which is why no one does).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you know how to modify it for the case when the zeros are not simple (see Peter Humphries’ comment). I will accept your answer in any case, over the weekend.

Comment: @EGME Yes, I wrote this answer in suggestive way for multiple zeros. You still use the Laurent expansions. The difference is that there are more terms in the expansion of $\zeta$ around the multiple zero. Then you ask yourself the same question: how do you choose terms from each Laurent expansion to get a term of the form $c (s - \rho)^{-1}$? Then you add all these together. The number of possibilities grows (quickly) with the degree of the root.